# SPA Angular Best Practices for Object Actions and Updates

Tags: angular, single-page-application

Our one customer has a rather large "order object" which has plenty of what I would call sub-objects to it.  It's not just a house, but it's the permits, the plans, the subcontractors, the financials, etc. When we load up the "order", everything comes in lickity split and we have tabs upon tabs all with lazy loading, etc.  So the end user experience is actually pretty nice.

We are now being tasked with allowing the users to interact with the order view and there are three solutions being proposed:

**Individual Tabs are their Own World**

1. Each tab is tied to its own updates and actions.  So the save/update button on the permitting tab only saves the information on that tab, and when actions are performed, just the permitting "sub-object" is sent to the API when permits need to be requested, printed, etc. Allows user not to worry about updating the whole enchilada and possibly updating things from other tabs they forgot they touched.

**Entire Order is Responsible for its own Updates and Actions**

2. The entire order is self maintaining, and when an update or action is requested, the entire order is sent back to the API. So if a county was changed on the property tab, and a permit is being requested and printed, the entire order object is sent with an "isDirty" flag on the property and permit sub-objects along with a "PrintPermit" action so the API knows what to update and then print the permit.

**Save, Then Action**

3. Any actions in a sub-object or tab is sent after the entire house order object is updated.  So if someone wants to order a permit, make sure the entire order is saved first, then just send a specific call to the API to order and print the permit versus having the API riddled with "Ifs" or "Cases" trying to figure out what actually needs to be done.

I realize this may sound like an "opinion" question, but it really is quite important to know what other teams are doing with something such as this, as front-end processing is so huge now and will only be getting larger.

Comment: I also realize this goes back to the old "god object" question of old.  However, with more emphasis being placed on grabbing a single object to reduce service calls to the API, I'm just wondering if the "rule" of splitting things into common actions/updates still applies when technically the entire object is relevant to the accurate processing of the smaller objects.

Comment: Personally, it depends on the common case.  Whenever I am confronted with a design question like this, I go to this principle.  What is more common?  As a user, am I generally configuring entire orders or only pieces at a time?  Am I configuring then requesting something?  All of your solutions have their pros and cons.  I would decide based on which solution best serves the common case.

Comment: @MichaelPalmer - Definitely a sound answer and helpful to know that it really does depend on the commonality versus any one particular method.